# Replacing links to images with images with JQuery

Tags: jquery, django

I am not quite experienced in JQuery but basically I am trying to build an blog ish website using django. Now I want to add images to the post and I am using this method which works fine in pure html but it doesen't seem to work with django:

```html
<html
><head></head>
    <body>
        <p>Some text with http://example.com/image.png and image and <span> nested http://example.com/second.png</span> image and an <img src="https://drop.ndtv.com/albums/AUTO/porsche-taycan-turbo/6401200x900_1_640x480.jpg"> img <span>foo</span> tag</p>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
        jQuery(function () {jQuery('body').find('*').contents().filter(function() {
          return this.nodeType == 3;
        }).each(function(i, elem)
                {
                    var matches = /(.*)(http:\/\/\S+(?:\.png|\.jpg|\.gif))(.*)/g.exec(elem.wholeText);
                    if (matches)
                    {
                        var parent = elem.parentNode;
                        var before = matches[1];
                        var replace = jQuery('<a />').attr('href', matches[2]).append(jQuery('<img />').attr('href', matches[2]))[0];
                        var after = matches[3];
                        parent.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(before), elem);
                        parent.insertBefore(replace, elem);
                        parent.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(after), elem);
                        parent.removeChild(elem);
                    }
                });});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my django template where I want to use it:

```html
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block title %}{{ object.title }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <article class="media content-section">
            <img class="rounded-circle article-img " src="{{object.author.profile.image.url}}"><!--adding pfp beside blog posts-->
            <class="media-body">
                <div class="article-metadata">
                    <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' object.author.username %}">{{ object.author }}</a>
                    <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
                    <small class="text-muted">{{ object.category }}</small>
                    {% if object.author == user %}
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                            <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-update' object.id %}">Update</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-delete' object.id %}">Delete</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <h2 class="text-muted">{{ object.title }}</h2>
                <p class="article-content">{{ object.content }}</p>
            </div>
    </article>
{% endblock %}
{% block scripts %}
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
        jQuery(function () {jQuery('body').find('*').contents().filter(function() {
          return this.nodeType == 3;
        }).each(function(i, elem)
                {
                    var matches = /(.*)(http:\/\/\S+(?:\.png|\.jpg|\.gif))(.*)/g.exec(elem.wholeText);
                    if (matches)
                    {
                        var parent = elem.parentNode;
                        var before = matches[1];
                        var replace = jQuery('<a />').attr('href', matches[2]).append(jQuery('<img />').attr('href', matches[2]))[0];
                        var after = matches[3];
                        parent.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(before), elem);
                        parent.insertBefore(replace, elem);
                        parent.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(after), elem);
                        parent.removeChild(elem);
                    }
                });});
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

But it does not seem to work in Django at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Your browser's debugging tools will help you narrow down the problem.  First, define "doesn't work".  What *does* happen?  Check the browser's development console, is there any error or warning?  Use the browser's script debugger by placing breakpoints in the functions to pause execution and step through it observing what happens.  Does the code execute at all?  When debugging, where specifically does it fail?